# Bullet numbering not aligned properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using webly sleek ui light font on a page.

When I use the font on bullet numbering, it does not align properly. As can be seen on image.
I try to change font to open sans, but still the same. It gets better on arial but still feels not right.

[image]

Comment: where's your source code?

Comment: I'm using twitter bootstrap and it's just normal ordered bullet list

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navlist
{
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;
}

#navlist li
{
padding-left: 10px;
list-style-type:lower-alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is corrected **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyTCH/)**

**CSS**

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
body {
    font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    padding:20px;
    }

ol {
    list-style-type:lower-alpha;
    color:#4E4E4E;
    background-color:inherit;
    padding:0 0 5px 30px;
}
ol li {
    padding-bottom:7px; 

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ol>
    <li>Testing 1</li>
    <li>Testing 2</li>
    <li>Testing 3</li>
    <li>Testing 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I see your fiddle, and when I try to change to 'Open Sans' font with font 15px, the problem appears again. It works on Arial font. Is it font problem or there are css problem?